# Perl LWP Post form-data with my boundary

Tags: perl, http, post, multipartform-data, lwp

I want to post data with content type `multipart/form-data`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->post (
    'http://127.0.0.1:12555',
    'Content-Type' => 'form-data',
    Content => {
        'data1' => rand,
        'data2' => rand,
    }
);
```

And i tested the submitted data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Socket qw ( inet_aton );

my $sock_listen = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
    LocalPort => '12555',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 3,
    Reuse => 1,
);
$sock_listen->autoflush ();

my $sock;
while ( $sock = $sock_listen->accept ( ) )
{
    my $data = '';
    $sock->recv ( $data, 4096 );
    print $data . "\n";
}
```

Test #1 result:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Host: 127.0.0.1:12555
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.05
Content-Length: 162
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data2"

0.876556396484375
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data1"

0.62921142578125
--xYzZY--
```

Test #2 result:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Host: 127.0.0.1:12555
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.05
Content-Length: 163
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data2"

0.896942138671875
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data1"

0.041656494140625
--xYzZY--
```

I added a data:

```
        'data3' => '--xYzZY'
```

and got:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Host: 127.0.0.1:12555
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.05
Content-Length: 221
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Tegj

--Tegj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data2"

0.34613037109375
--Tegj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data3"

--xYzZY
--Tegj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data1"

0.678955078125
--Tegj--
```

The question is how i can set the `boundary` manually to 32 chars string like browser's `----WebKitFormBoundary[...]` using `LWP`?

Or can just use `IO::Socket`?

Comment: i just notice that Chrome and IE create different boundary format a bit.

Comment: This is a very nice post, IMO.  But: why would you want to set a specific boundary?  First, the  purpose of it is to separate message parts so the only thing about it is that it doesn't exist anywhere in the message.  It needn't be "the same" as any other (and you can't ensure that since none are guaranteed to stay the same).   Besides, setting it to anything fixed is bad -- what if that string shows up in a message?

Comment: I would start by reading the source of LWP. It will probably take you to HTTP::Message. There you will see how the boundary is set. You can probably either overwrite it, attach something to it or reach into the object to change it. But I agree that it's questionable why you would want to do that.

Comment: @simbabque It's used from the `HTTP::Request::Common`, and the code strongly implies that it isn't even possible to set it (without badly violating the module).

Comment: @zdim I don't have access to a computer right now, so I made an educated guess. It would be possible to subclass somehow. It patch it in I guess. Class::Method::Modifiers as a monkey patch alternative could work. But I should look at the code first, and I'm not going to search for it on my phone. ;-)

Comment: @simbabque  I lightly mention what goes on in the code in the answer ... have a look at the source when you get to it, it is interesting to see whether one _can_ somehow mess with that (in at least a somewhat reasonable way).

Comment: @zdim I'm looking now. I think it should be pretty easy to overwrite. I'll hack something up. By the way, the [metacpan source view](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/HTTP-Message-6.13/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm#L292) is much nicer to use.

Comment: @zdim found it. It's actually built-in, though not very well documented. Took me a bit of searching and a few minutes with the debugger.

Comment: A nice debugging aid for this kind of situation besides your totally appropriate IO::Socket solution is [LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere). You can just drop that into your code anywhere you want, and it will dump out a pretty version of everything that goes over the wire and back. Together with a very short timeout and an address that doesn't respond it would work here, too.  I've given [a lightning talk about it at TPCiA](https://youtu.be/ERcN7jGeEzA?t=15m23s) this year, which explains nicely how it works.

Comment: Do you realise that there's nothing wrong with that last message? It's far from clear why you would want to alter the separator, as it carries no information and needs only to be a sequence that doesn't appear elsewhere in the content. LWP has chosen `--Tegj` which is fine.

Comment: i can "imagine" how boundary is, although don't know the exact algorithm yet that create boundary by browsers.

i saw some topics explaining how that content type works and we can set the boundary manually, and i'm doubtful how to make it with Perl. that's the cause of question.

Comment: @simbabque  Nice one. (I had briefly tried to slip it in but not in a right way.)  To nitpick on phrasing, I wouldn't call it a "_built-in_" but would rather say that you found a (clean) way to slip it in and that this is likely not an intended "_feature_."  Importantly, it _is_ safe since it does undergo the rest of checks etc.

Comment: @zdim I think it's a feature. There is code there that explicitly reads it. There is probably something in the RFC that defines this behavior. But let's not fret over that. There is a fairly easy way to do it. We found it. Problem solved. :-)

Comment: @simbabque Sure :) ... but I also didn't look at the code carefully enough to see that it specifically looks for the word `boundary` in what is passed.  May really be a feature after all.

Answer (score 2):

The sole purpose of the boundary is to separate the message parts and the only requirement on it is that it doesn't appear anywhere in the message.   I don't see a good reason to attempt to set it to be "the same" as anything else.  Besides, no tool guarantees that it will always use the same one.

More importantly, setting it to a fixed string (without regard for the message) is dangerous: how does anyone know that such a string may not be in a message?

Finally, I don't think it is possible to do so, precisely because the boundary must be *checked* to ensure that it indeed isn't in the message; so no tool should provide a way to set it to a predefined string.

Have a look at [HTTP::Request::Common's source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/OALDERS/HTTP-Message-6.13/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm). See how the sub `boundary()` badly mangles the string to return, and how much work goes into the boundary elsewhere. Then `CHECK_BOUNDARY:` block changes it further if it isn't good enough. This is clearly not meant to be set outside.

The `post` method of `LWP::UserAgent` exists as a shortcut for this module's one.

---

Note that [simbabque found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651572/4653379) to set the boundary, which then also undergoes the checks.

Answer (score 2):

LWP allows you set the boundary manually when you do `multipart/form-data` requests. This feature is unfortunately not documented at all.

However, you **have to do** `multipart` explicitly. You can set your own boundary by appending the *boundary* as an additional field of the `Content-Type`. It will be [converted to a header appropriately by HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/HTTP-Message-6.13/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm#L50).

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:12555',
    'Content-Type' => 
        'multipart/form-data;boundary=Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall',
         # ^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^

    Content => {
        data1 => rand,
        data2 => rand,
    },
);
```

With your listener, this result in the following output.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Host: 127.0.0.1:12555
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.15
Content-Length: 269
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall

--Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data2"

0.0575856828104122
--Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data1"

0.677908250902878
--Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall--
```

Note that HTTP::Request::Common will replace your boundary with a random string if it finds the boundary string in the body of any of the parts. It will not just add a number to your boundary.